# How to detect if a block is finalized already in block import

Tags: block-import

I have written a simple `block` import that wraps grandpa block import, it does tiny verification and calls grandpa block import after that, it looks like this:

```rs
pub struct CustomBlockImport<I> {
    grandpa_block_import: I,
}
#[async_trait::async_trait]
impl<I: sc_consensus::BlockImport<Block>> sc_consensus::BlockImport<Block> for WitnessBlockImport<I>
where
    I: Send,
{
    type Error = ConsensusError;
    type Transaction = I::Transaction;

    async fn check_block(
        &mut self,
        block: BlockCheckParams<Block>,
    ) -> Result<ImportResult, Self::Error> {
return self
                .grandpa_block_import
                .import_block(block, cache)
                .await
                .map_err(|e| ConsensusError::ClientImport(format!("{}", e)))
    }

    async fn import_block(
        &mut self,
        block: BlockImportParams<Block, Self::Transaction>,
        cache: HashMap<well_known_cache_keys::Id, Vec<u8>>,
    ) -> Result<ImportResult, Self::Error> {
// if block is already finalized no need for my custom verification, just run grandpa block import      
if block.finalized {
            log::info!("block already finalized");
return self
                .grandpa_block_import
                .import_block(block, cache)
                .await
                .map_err(|e| ConsensusError::ClientImport(format!("{}", e)))
        }
        // do some verification
        return self
            .grandpa_block_import
            .import_block(block, cache)
            .await
            .map_err(|e| ConsensusError::ClientImport(format!("{}", e)))
    }
}
```

I tried using `block.finalized` field to detect whether its already finalized or not however in my simple network, I start three authorities  (Alice, Bob, Charlie) and delay running the final authority (Dave) after quite some time (so that the first three get to finalize some blocks); when I start the Dave node, it does not log `block already finalized` as it should, instead it goes and do my custom verification logic.

why is this happening and how to solve this?

Comment: Removing my comment as @bkchr's answer is correct

Answer (score 2):

`block.finalized` is only set by `manual-seal` to instant finalize a block.

There is no definitive way to check if a block is already finalized on block import. You could check if `justifications` is `Some(_)`, but even that would only be the case for the blocks where the authority set changed and thus, we have a justification.

When importing blocks at the tip of the chain, they will also not be directly finalized. It takes some time until blocks are finalized.

You could check after calling `grandpa.block_import`, if the block is finalized. However, as I said above only every Xth block that enacts an authority set would be finalized.

Comment: Are justifications only to be found in blocks with authority set changes?

Comment: When doing a full sync yes. At the tip of the chain we always keep the justification of the latest finalized block as well.

Comment: Apologies, I missed the context of the question. But to clarify; when a node has to sync with the network it can determine the finality of a block instantly if there were authority set changes in that particular block. Otherwise it will find the justification, that finalizes the block, at a later block (doesn't have to be a block with authority set changes), correct?

Comment: When you finalize block X later and Y is an ancestor of it, Y will be finalized as well.

> Otherwise it will find the justification, that finalizes the block, at a later block (doesn't have to be a block with authority set changes), correct?

So, yes!

Comment: so basically the information that a block is finalized is most of the time off-chain and sometimes on-chain with the justification field, so my question is, how would clients (simple users) would know whether a block is finalized or not since they can't rely on justifications

Comment: You can ask a node what the hash of a block at block.number is. If the returned hash is the same as block.hash(), then you know that it is finalized.